# Finding min value for date across rows in R

Tags: r, date, merge, tidyverse

I have the tables below:

**1st Table:**

| ID | Rejected | New | Expired |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2021-02-21 | 2022-03-20 | 2021-05-20 |
| 001 | 2021-02-21 | 2022-03-20 | 2021-05-20 |
| 002 | 2021-06-21 | NA | 2021-06-20 |
| 002 | 2021-06-21 | NA | 2021-06-20 |
| 003 | 2021-05-20 | NA | 2021-05-20 |
| 003 | 2021-05-20 | NA | 2021-05-20 |
| 004 | 2021-05-20 | 2021-11-03 | 2022-06-20 |
| 004 | 2021-05-20 | 2021-11-03 | 2022-06-20 |
| 005 | 2021-05-20 | 2021-11-03 | 2022-06-20 |
| 005 | 2021-05-20 | 2021-11-03 | 2022-06-20 |

**2nd Table:**

| ID | date |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 2021-04-30 |
| 002 | 2021-04-30 |
| 003 | 2021-04-30 |
| 004 | 2021-04-30 |
| 005 | 2021-04-30 |

**Desired Output:**

| ID | Rejected | New | Expired |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2021-02-21 | 2021-02-21 | 2021-05-20 |
| 001 | 2021-02-21 | 2021-02-21 | 2021-05-20 |
| 002 | 2021-06-21 | 2021-04-30 | 2021-06-21 |
| 002 | 2021-06-21 | 2021-04-30 | 2021-06-21 |
| 003 | 2021-05-20 | 2021-04-30 | 2021-05-20 |
| 003 | 2021-05-20 | 2021-04-30 | 2021-05-20 |
| 004 | 2021-03-20 | 2021-03-20 | 2022-06-20 |
| 004 | 2021-03-20 | 2021-03-20 | 2022-06-20 |
| 005 | 2021-05-20 | 2021-05-20 | 2022-06-20 |
| 005 | 2021-05-20 | 2021-05-20 | 2022-06-20 |

**What I want**:

1. Merge table 1 and 2 by ID only for values where table1$new is **not** NA. (I.e. all NA values in table1 should be filled with date values from table2)
2. After merging, merge$new dates cannot occur after rejected or expired. One solution could be finding the minimum value in each row and placing that in New.

**My Code**:

```
table2 <- q1 %>% ##Create new dataset min_val from q1##
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.min(date)) %>% ##find min value from each row##
  rename(New2 = date)   ## rename the createdatetime to New2##

merged <- table1 %>% #merge merged_final.1 to min_val##
  left_join(table2, by = 'ID') %>% 
  mutate(New = coalesce(New, New2)) %>% ##This will make sure only NA value are replaced
  select(-New2) ##drop New2 column##

merged$New <- as.Date(apply(merged[, c(2, 3, 4)], 1, FUN = min))
```

**Issue**

This last line of code does not seem to be working for me. When I run this, many of the merged$new values  turn to NA and the previously NA rows of merge$rejected and merge$expired are suddenly filled with random dates.

Any help would be appreciated. Also not sure why my third table isn't showing up in html format.

Comment: @onyambu I am not sure what this means. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry. I thought it was python. It turns out to be R

Comment: Check the response below

Comment: Your starting data is different with regards to Rejected date on ID2 as compared to the one in the desired output

Comment: Apologies! Will fix now

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left_join` then `coalesce` the two columns

```
library(tidyverse)

left_join(df1, df2) %>%
    mutate(New = pmin(Rejected, coalesce(New, date), Expired), date = NULL)

   ID   Rejected        New    Expired
1   1 2021-02-21 2021-02-21 2021-05-20
2   1 2021-02-21 2021-02-21 2021-05-20
3   2 2021-03-21 2021-03-21 2021-05-20
4   2 2021-03-21 2021-03-21 2021-05-20
5   3 2021-05-20 2021-04-30 2021-05-20
6   3 2021-05-20 2021-04-30 2021-05-20
7   4 2021-05-20 2021-05-20 2022-06-20
8   4 2021-05-20 2021-05-20 2022-06-20
9   5 2021-05-20 2021-05-20 2022-06-20
10  5 2021-05-20 2021-05-20 2022-06-20
```

Comment: Row 3 and 4 of  `New` are not as the desired output. Maybe you can check?

Comment: @TarJae that is because Row 3 and 4 of Rejected in the original data is different from the Row 3 and 4 rejected of desired data

Comment: Hi, this worked! Could you explain to me how to interpret this part of code:

(New = pmin(Rejected, coalesce(New, date), Expired), date = NULL)

Is the interpretation: New will equal the minimum value between rejected, new, and expired?

Comment: @JohnTayson yes. New is the minimum of the three. Then get rid of date.

Comment: Last question, is there a reason to do a left join rather than a merge?

Comment: @TarJae you have never used `... = NULL` before within mutate?

Comment: @JohnTayson left join is the same as merge with `all.x =TRUE` merge by default does an inner join. In this case whether a left join and an inner join both will be the same since all the IDs in df1 are present in df2. If that was not the case, then the results would have been different

Comment: @onyambu. I think not. So I really had often the situation to remove one specific column at the end of pipe. Many thanks for this!

Comment: @onyambu Follow up question, if a value for new already existed, how can I make sure that the pmin function does not apply to those rows?

Comment: @JohnTayson use `ifelse` ie `ifelse(is.na(New), pmin(Rejected, coalesce(New, date), Expired), New)`

Comment: @onyambu and this would be inside the mutate statement? Like this:

`merged <- left_join(merged, min_val) %>%
  mutate(ifelse(is.na(New), pmin(Rejected, coalesce(New, New2), Expired, Pending, Approved, Note, Invoiced, Invoice_Rejected, Invoice_Rejected_Needs_Credit, Credited), New)) %>% 
  select(-New) %>% 
  rename(New = New2)`